# Two approaches yield different results

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Here's the statement problem:

"From an ordinary deck of playing cards, cards are to be drawn successively at random and without replacement. The probability that the third spade appears on the sixth draw is computed as follows: Let A be the event of two spades in the first five cards drawn, and let B be the event of a spade on the sixth draw. Thus, the probability that we wish to compute is P(A ∩ B)."

**The conditional probability approach:** We have that $\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c} 13 \\ 2 \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} 39 \\ 3 \end{array} \right)}{\left( \begin{array}{c} 52 \\ 5 \end{array} \right)}$ and $P(B|A) = \frac{11}{47}$, so the desired probability, $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B|A)= \frac{\left( \begin{array}{c} 13 \\ 2 \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} 39 \\ 3 \end{array} \right) \times 11}{\left( \begin{array}{c} 52 \\ 5 \end{array} \right) \times47}$

**The classical approach** We have that $P(A \cap B) = \frac{N(A\cap B)}{N(S)}$, where $S$ is our sample space. We have that $N(A\cap B) = \left( \begin{array}{c} 13 \\ 2 \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} 39 \\ 3 \end{array} \right){\left( \begin{array}{c} 11 \\ 1 \end{array} \right)}$, because we want to choose 2 spades out of 13 spades, then 3 non-spades of the remaining 39 cards, and then 6th position is one the spades in the 11 spades. On the other hand, $N(S) = \left( \begin{array}{c} 52 \\ 6 \end{array} \right)$, so we have $P(A \cap B) = \frac{\left( \begin{array}{c} 13 \\ 2 \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} 39 \\ 3 \end{array} \right){\left( \begin{array}{c} 11 \\ 1 \end{array} \right)}}{\left( \begin{array}{c} 52 \\ 6 \end{array} \right)}$.

The two approaches should yield the same result, but here they' re not. Also, I noticed that while the numerators are the same, the denominators are different (though not too much). Where was I wrong?

Comment: You have an error in your second approach.  The first approach is the correct one.  If you wanted to do it the second way, then consider fixing it by insisting that order of cards matters.  You would have instead the numerator being $\binom{13}{2}\binom{39}{3}\cdot 5!\cdot \binom{11}{1}$ as the order that the first five cards can appear in can vary, and then the denominator as $\binom{52}{6}6!$, which should show that you are off by a factor of $\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: You can think of the error in the second as being that although we designated a specific "*third*" spade it would able to occur in any of the six positions, even before the other two spades, since we were calculating without respect to card order.

Comment: I will point out one more observation.  The probability that the sixth card is a spade is $\frac{1}{4}=0.25$.  Your second answer without having corrected it winds up being approximately $0.385$.  Having the third spade occur as the sixth card is a much more restrictive situation that merely having *any* spade be the sixth card, be it the first one to occur, second, third, etc... so we should have expected the probability to be *less* than $\frac{1}{4}$, not greater, immediately implying that the second answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first calculation is the correct one.

To convince you of this, you can take your attempts and try to apply the same formula to smaller examples.  Briefly take a look at the related question of where we have a three-card deck: an ace of spades, a two of spades, and an ace of hearts.  We ask the question of what is the probability that we draw our second spade as the third card.

By brute force listing out of the six possibilities, you should see that four of the six yield a spade as the last card.

Using the first approach, we would arrive at the same correct answer: $\frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}}{\binom{3}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{1}=\frac{2}{3}$

Using the second approach, we would have arrived at a wrong answer: $\frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}\binom{1}{1}}{\binom{3}{3}}=2$, which happens to be off by a factor of three.

---

To fix your second calculation, it might be easiest to explain by instead of working in the scenario that order of cards in hand don't matter, that we work in the scenario where order of cards in hand *do* matter.

We approach the same way: $\binom{13}{2}$ ways to pick the early spades, $\binom{39}{3}$ ways to pick the other early cards, and then $\binom{11}{1}$ ways to pick the final spade.  We then pick in what specific order the cards appeared in $5!$ ways, noting that the final spade *must* occur in the *final* position and nowhere else.

The bottom, similarly, will be $\binom{52}{6}6!$ as after picking what six cards apppear, we can arrange them in $6!$ ways.

This gives our corrected calculation at $$\frac{\binom{13}{2}\binom{39}{3}\binom{11}{1}5!}{\binom{52}{6}6!}=\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{\binom{13}{2}\binom{39}{3}\binom{11}{1}}{\binom{52}{6}}$$

which one can verify is equal to the answer given by your first attempt.

As discussed in comments elsewhere, that $6$ happens to be equal to $3!$ is merely a coincidence.  We divide by $6$ since that is the number of cards in the hand, just as dividing by three and not by $2!$ corrected the calculation in the smaller three-card deck example above.

A different way of picturing the correction is that in the second attempt without the fix, we did not account for the final card actually appearing in the final position.  The final card actually appears in the final position with probability $\frac{1}{6}$ (*or more generally $\frac{1}{n}$ if referring to drawing $n$ cards*), and so this should have been multiplied in as well.

---

Another example to try to convince that dividing by $n$ is the correct fix and not dividing by the factorial of the number of spades:

Consider the problem of asking what the probability that the *first* spade occurs in the $6$'th draw.

The first approach, again the correct one, would give an answer of $\frac{\binom{39}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}\cdot\frac{13}{47}$

The second approach without the fix would give an answer of $\frac{\binom{39}{5}\binom{13}{1}}{\binom{52}{6}}$, an answer *six* times larger than the first, just as before, despite the number of spades having changed between the examples.  Dividing by the factorial of the number of spades would not have corrected it.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I guess the most important thing to understand about this problem is that **order matters** because we're not focusing on the hand, but instead on the event that the third spade appears on the 6th draw. This has a strong effect on the outcome space. The most difficult aspect for me when studying probability (and also combinatorics) is that I have a very weak understanding of outcome space, hence resulting in double counting, missing, etc.

Comment: I wonder if you could help me answer this question? It's a very interesting one. Thanks in advance.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635140/why-pa-cap-b-neq-pb-cap-a

Comment: It both does and doesn't.  The order in which the first five cards appear doesn't matter in the slightest.  Only the sixth card matters.  One could just as readily described the sample space as being all ways to select five cards in any order followed by a sixth.

Comment: @huytruong your linked question in the comment above already has a fine answer given. The short answer is that it is not simply "c1 fails and c2 fails" it is instead "c1 is flipped first and fails and c2 is flipped second as c2 fails", which is distinctly different than "c1 is flipped second and fails while c2 is flipped first and fails"